# Change ActionBar overlay from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I am using ActionBar Compat with NavigationDrawer from this source [NavigationDrawer using only Android Support Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473127/navigationdrawer-using-only-android-support-library) 
 I have a NavigationDrawer with some items, each item is a Fragment. Is it possible to change ActionBar overlay mode from Fragment to Fragment? I´d like to make ActionBar transparent in grid view, but keep it opaque in other case. How do I set this from Fragment?

Comment: can you please tell me how you did this? I also have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your fragment call, `getActivity()` and cast to `ActionBarActivity` with a  `getSupportActionBar()`

```
    // Update activity title
    ActionBar actionBar = ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("lorem ipsum");
```

For making it transparent,  have a look at this blog post:
http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2013/11/20/making-your-action-bar-not-boring/

Comment: Ok, I did it the other way. But the link you gave seems relative, so +1 from me

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question I believe - the link provided explains how to do overlay the action bar for the whole app, not just one fragment