# navigation drawer, slide menu, page slide are supported in which android version

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, slidingmenu

I am trying to make an e-store app

i would like to design it like gmail app

but after browsing the links

- http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/android-tutorial-using-the-viewpager.html
- http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

also other links and android tutorial videos in youtube

but i couldnt find

1. from which android version the navigation drawer, action bar, swipe views arr supported
2. all the tutorials of sliding menu, navigation drawer etc shows only fragment displaying text view/image view

I want to have different layout

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please refrain from begging against downvotes.  Please also make an effort to spell things properly and use correct grammar, as doing so *drastically* increases the chances of good answers.  Please also be sure to try basic internet searches *before* asking a question.  Try entering `android navigation drawer api level`, `android action bar api level` and `android swipe view api level` into your favorite search engine (hint: Google is good), and you should see all of your answers on the very first page of results for each.

Comment: i do apologies for my grammar and questioning i need few time to settle well so please don't down vote me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. from which android version the navigation drawer, action bar, swipe views arr supported

Normally from `HoneyComb` navigation drawer and action bar are supported but u can use these from `Eclair(android 2.1)` with the help of `android-support-v7-appcompat` library and for that instead of `Activity` u have to use `ActionBarActivity` .

> 2. all the tutorials of sliding menu, navigation drawer etc shows only fragment displaying text view/image view i want to have different
>   layout

Instead of ImageView or TextView u can load ur own layout

[Demo project on Navigation Drawer for android 2.1 and upper](https://github.com/BradleyRL/NavDrawerExampleAppCompat-v7)

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473127/navigationdrawer-using-only-android-support-library)

Comment: Please *refrain* from `adding` random **formatting** to words that you `think` are *important*.  It makes your content very hard to read.  `Backtick formatting` is for *code*, not emphasis.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use all of this in my app which requires API lvl 10 (Android 2.3.3).
Implemented with Android Support Library.