# Navigation Drawer with Page Sliding example

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, android, android-menu

Android noob over here. I'm trying to find a good example of a navigation drawer with tabs (like google play store). I found this example on GitHub but I wasn't able to make it work under Android Studio. It depends on PagerSlidingTabStrip and ActionBarSherlock.

https://github.com/Balaji-K13/Navigation-drawer-page-sliding-tab-strip

Do you guys know any other working example or fork that runs with less dependencies?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at Dev Apps Direct https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inappsquared.devappsdirect&hl=en It has a couple of examples of what you're looking for (thought, I haven't taken the time to see how many dependencies those open source example projects have, you'll have to do that research yourself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[One example here](https://github.com/BradleyRL/NavDrawerExampleAppCompat-v7), source : [StackoverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473127/navigationdrawer-using-only-android-support-library)

I am using it. You should also give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

I would check out the `FlyOutContainer` class, if you've ever used the StackOverFlow app it's sort of like that sliding navigation tab.

https://github.com/garuma/FlyOutMenu/blob/master/FlyOutMenu/FlyOutContainer.cs

Here's a really good tutorial from YouTube regarding the `FlyOutContainer` class

http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=YeR7McJIltk

Here you are relying on one dependency.

Comment: What? this is for Xamarin.Android.