# Jfeinstein Sliding Menu over Activity

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I use [this](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/) library to implement slide menu in my app. It works that it push my activity content to left side. I want to Sliding Menu appear OVER my activity content. Is there any way to change appearing of this sliding menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it. Instead of that library you have to use [Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

For supporting from `android 2.1` you have to use `Support Library`.

- [NavigationDrawer using only Android Support Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473127/navigationdrawer-using-only-android-support-library)
- https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html
- https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: Thanks! :) If I understand you corectly there is no way to do that in jfeinstein Sliding Menu right?

Comment: perhaps i'm not sure but what u want u can do that using `NavigationDrawer` download the sample and try it. Its very easy to implement.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, Jfeinstein Sliding Menu uses iOS style and push content to the left (with ActionBar)

The recommended way is using Android-styled component: Navigation Drawer. It appears over content and below ActionBar.

https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

it's only your choise, but in my mind using android recommended way is prefer